# How to create datepicker style input fields

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to implement an input field that has predefined set of possible values say (1 to 200). But I want the interface to be like the datepicker control where the user can just swipe to select rather than input using keyboard. Is this possible? Can anyone tell me how to go about implementing it? I am new to mobile development and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a NumberPicker. Here are some examples http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2078060&seqNum=2
and
https://www.google.be/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=numberpicker%20android

Comment: Thanks. But I am not trying to implement a datepicker. i just want the selection style of the datepicker. Also not on a dialog, but on the parent screen itself.

Comment: I have edited my question for better clarity. To be exact I want to use this field for user to select his pulse and blood pressure rather than a date. So basically user selects a value between 1 to 200 or 1 to 120 etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Let me work on this and get back to you.